# How to check how many milliseconds passed in some event(java)

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating time difference in Milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707938/calculating-time-difference-in-milliseconds)

How i can check how many milliseconds passed in some event in java?
For example:

```
Want to start timer here<<
   function doSomething()
   .
   .
Want to finish timer here<<
```

I want to check how many milliseconds passed. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707938/calculating-time-difference-in-milliseconds

Comment: If this is CPU intensive and you are looking to benchmark this function I suggest you run it at least 10,000 times to warm up the code, start the timer and run it repeatedly for 2-10 seconds.  You should use System.nanoTime() as you may find it takes less than a milli-second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

DoStuff();

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long millis = endTime - startTime;
```

Answer (score 9):

```
System.nanoTime()
```

and compare the start value to end value. Here is the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29).

> Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer,
>   in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.nanotime()` before and after the action and then subtract the values and divide by 1e6 to get time in ms.

Comment: I think you mean divide by 1000000 to get ms.  There is 100 ns in a mico-second and 1000 micro-seconds in a ms.

Comment: I'm sorry @PeterLawrey, my bad! Last day of work the brain refuses to work ;)

Comment: I would write 1000000 or 1e6 as 10^6 can be confused for `10 ^ 6` which is 12. ;)

Comment: True story @PeterLawrey, EE + programmer problems ;D

Comment: lol. 10e6 = 10 ^^ 7, It would be just `1e6` for a million.

Comment: I'm done with this, I'm out LOL