# Java equivalent syntax for time difference code in C#

Tags: java, c#, datetime

How can be write below c# code in java?

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now; 

//some code

Duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
```

value in Duration variable is float.

Comment: you may find what you are looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707938/calculating-time-difference-in-milliseconds

Comment: Thanks @Maylo, the solution given in above link worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty the same.

```
Date startTime = new Date(); 

//some code

long duration = new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime();
```

Comment: Don’t use the long outdated `Date` class. In this case `System.currentTimeMillis()` suffices. If you want a date-time class, use `Instant` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).